# How can I save a class when a batch job is running (without the Ant tool)

Tags: apex, batch, class, asyncapexjob

I am trying to figure out if we can save a class which is used in a batch job.

I am unable to save a class. I can't save the class when a batch job is running. I don't want to abort the job. Is there another way, except the Ant tool, I can save this class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Setup | Deployment Settings | Allow deployments of components when corresponding Apex jobs are pending or in progress.
```

> Caution: Enabling this option may cause Apex jobs to fail.

The above applies to deploying into a target org

If you are developing in a sandbox, and you are editing an apex class that is used in a running job of that sandbox, you need to abort the job in order to save the class.

Comment: Also available via the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploymentsettings.htm). Still not a good idea.

Comment: I also did that but it's not working, so I am in a sandbox I also can't deploy on this sandbox, but I can't abort the job.

Comment: see updated answer; why can't you abort the job in your sandbox?

Comment: @Malik You won't be able to save (Tooling restriction). You can use workbench, sfdx, ant toolkit, etc, but the Developer Console won't be able to.